# External selection applied to custom QAbstractItemModel

Tags: c++, qt

I have a custom subclass of QAbstractItemModel. Users may select rows from the model directly in a QListView but *also* externally (the tree view lists geometric vertices, edges, and faces which can also be selected in a non-Qt OpenGL view). Children of any given index are determined on demand. If no Qt view has caused children in the model to be determined and those children are selected externally, how can a program update the Qt selection model to include new indices as they are added in response to users expanding items with children?

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly (get) *selectionModel()* of your item view. And after use 
*[virtual slot] void QItemSelectionModel::select(const QModelIndex &index, QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags command)*